# UML sequence diagram for php form submit

Tags: php, forms, uml, form-submit, sequence-diagram

I'm trying the create two UML diagrams over the submit process of a php application (before/after design change). I realize my UML have gotten very rusty and I'm in doubt that my diagrams are correct, though I think it visually describes the process very good.

**The first one (before I changed the design).**

1. User enter the CMS page (manage.php)
2. Manage.php starts building the html, for this it requires some db data.
3. 5-10 seconds later the CMS is ready and shown as html for the user.
4. The user chose some page containing a form to be edited (there are multiply pages, each have their own form which edits different things).
5. The user edits/changes the form. (all forms were loaded with current settings in step 2)
6. User clicks the submit button. All form data is sent to processor.php and the cms page dies?? (the form refreshes the page).
7. The users is validated with some session stuff (facebook sdk) returns success.
8. The processor identifies the action (which of the forms were edited).
9. The processor validates the data received, (it was OK) returns success.
10. The processor sends a CRUD operation to the DB. success!
11. The processor sets some headers and give a response to the client.
12. The CMS reloads everything and get the new data from the db.
13. When finished loading the user get the html page again.

[image]
How can I show that CMS and its js dies? (red X) and how can i show that it is instantiated again (blue ->) ??

**Change in design**

Because this design was poor I decided to change it. Instead of submitting a form and reloading the entire CMS every time a little form was edited. I decided to submit the changes asynchronous with jQuery ajax request. The CMS page is never refreshed, and the "save" process is now lightspeed instead of 5-10 seconds.

1. User enter the CMS page (manage.php)
2. Manage.php starts building the html, for this it requires some db data.
3. A loading screen shows up (early as possible)
4. 5-10 seconds later the CMS is ready and shown as html for the user.
5. The user chose some page containing a form to be edited....
6. The user edits/changes the form....
7. User clicks the save button and triggers a function.
8. Form data is collected and assigned to a variable.
9. Before the ajax request is made, the button turns orange to signal that it is not read yet. it is also disabled.
10. The ajax request is made.
11. The users is validated...success.
12. The processor identifies the action....
13. The processor validates the data received....success.
14. The processor sends a CRUD operation to the DB. success!
15. The processor sets status 200 and give a response to the client.
16. The the ajax functions calls the success() function which turns the button green to signal that now it is done.

[image]
The validation process is the same. But the rest is new and I'm also unsure that this is correct. Both seems logical to me, but my logic sense is rarely the correct solution, especially when it comes to UML.

Comment: From a glance this looks okay. But in detail your question is way too broad.

Answer (score 2):

At least, on the first schema, i can provide following remarks:
- it is not so bad, i do not know your tool but it generates the diagram from the code no ?

- - choose page : strange start before the previous end
- manage.php can not be deleted and send a response
- iteration should be a loop : 17.6.3.17 Loop
  The interactionOperator loop designates that the CombinedFragment represents a loop. The loop operand will be
  repeated a number of times. And a guard to define loop condition.
- long execution is not logic with all messages. It is not executed by a message ...
- some messages cross this execution, it seems illogical since all messages are synchrone ...

The red boxes are ExecutionSpecification
"An ExecutionSpecification is a specification of the execution of a unit of Behavior or Action within the Lifeline."

For me, it model an action activated by a message.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for you help. I updated both images, with minor corrections. -- The "choose page" is a action done by the actor, the javascript handles that request and changes the content of the CMS (manage.php) which ?? is stile live? The red box means live/active right? Or does it mean that it is operating?? -- manage.php first sends a post request, then receives a response and refreshes. You means it should die (X) after it receives the response? Or how can I visually show that its currents state is completely replaced because the page reloads?

Comment: @ Rasmus Puls your red boxes are ExecutionSpecification i added a comment about that. The fact that a classifier is active or not is shown by the lifeline (the vertical dash line)

Comment: Aha, so in the second diagram i should shorten the "long" vertical execution boxes to only be present as code in that lane is executed. if it calls a method in another lane (and waits for return) I stop the red box and put an arrow over to the other lane where I can continue the red box. If it started a thread and kept running while the call in the other lane was running i could continue the red box in both lanes ?

Comment: Would you mind checking my answer and confirm that the new diagrams are correct (at least more correct). Thanks ;)

Comment: @Rasmus Puls far better, I check this evening (French time)

Comment: @Rasmus Puls you should not post your improvement as an answer but rather edit your question with the improvement.

Comment: @Rasmus Puls in the first schema you still have cross on dash line which means that the object does not participate to the diagram anymore but the object still receives or sends messsage. On your second schema, you have a return message orange button but a post after the return ... and the message identity action comes from nowhere. On success return there are two arrows ...  And the two return orange button and success are not logic. You combined fragment is not a loop as it should. Please delete your answer and edit your question with corrected schemas and try to ask a precise question.

Comment: The "orange button" arrow should indicate that the js function first sends back some css chaging the color of a button, and then afterward the same function sends a POST request to ajax_processor.php - A return message means that the execution returns and end? in that case, how can i indicate the the function sends something back to the actor but does not return/end ? If success is not logic what shall i write instead? true? the function validates and let the other code continue because validation succeeds.

Comment: @Rasmus Puls in this case, "orange button arrow" is a call like the others not a return message. For one execution, after the return message you can not send other message. The point about success it the two black arrow, one per call, so you get two call ? And i fell that "orange button" does no go to the actor but to Manage. i speak about the second schema only